# how to open my app by clicking any button in other installed apps

Tags: android

i like to open my own app by clicking any button in another installed app in my phone.

Example: when i click a delivery button in any shopping app then my app will open or my app icon will pop up in bottom.

( The same method used in insta download app for download Instagram picture, when we copy url of a instagram image the insta download app will pop up automatically )

is it possible??? if anyone knows please help me

Comment: Use Content Providers refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Comment: To handle actions in Android, you can use Intents.  Read the part under "Receiving an implicit Intent" here : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: @SaiKiran thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
   i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.yourApp");
if (i == null)
    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Comment: this is work only for my own application. when i use this code it launch only  another application by default from my application

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data and the action, you simply should add these information to your intent instance before starting it.

I am assuming you have access to the AndroidManifest of the other app, you can see all needed information there LIKE

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```